# macOS automatically opening unknown app that cannot be found

Tags: mac, catalina, malware

Since a few days ago I have been randomly getting this popup on my Mac. I cannot seem to locate the file via Terminal, Finder or Spotlight.

I'd rather not open it and see in case it could damage my Mac.

Is there any way to delete this file (Unix app?) or would I have to open it to find out what the cause is? Thanks in advance.

[image: Popup I have been getting]

[image: In Preferences > Security & Privacy > General]

Comment: To clarify when you say automatically opening it, do you mean randomly while the computer is on or at login/startup?

Comment: It opens randomly when the computer is on, and it also occasionally opens on startup.

Comment: It sounds like a background system application is being launched by the operating system and is being caught out by the security system. Did this happen after an upgrade to a new macOS version?

Comment: Most likely not from a software update as I haven't had a macos update since I bought my mac (currently on 10.15.2). I think it might have been a downloaded application if the unarchiver unzipped it, but I cannot seem to track the app down.

Comment: Is it always exactly the same character sequence, or is it random? I'd be inclined to run Malwarebytes over the machine, just in case. The format of the sequence suggests a UUID, which is a randomly-generated sequence, [theoretically] never to be repeated by any subsequent calculation.